# Vue JS - How to dynamically create tables

Tags: vue.js

I am looking to have a button where, when clicked, a new table is created. Is it possible to do so? I have searched across online for something like this, but I have not been able to find anything. All examples deal with a single table and adding/deleting rows from it.
The issue I run into is rendering the html table tags from Vue with the methods attached. That is where I have reached a road block. Also, I'm not so sure how I would be able to add rows based on the table. Would what I am trying to accomplish be possible?

**Update**

I am able to insert multiple components, but only if I hard-code them in the html.

**html**

```
<div class="temp">

    <temp></temp>
    <temp></temp>
    <temp></temp>


    </div>
```

With regards to Vue, I created a template component and everything is functioning as it should. My aim is to insert `<temp></temp>` onto the html page when a button is clicked, so that another table can be created.

**Vue**

```
Vue.component('temp', {
    template: '\
<div>\
    <table v-for="(name,i) in rows.slice(0,1)" :key="i">\ 
        <tr>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="name.exercise" placeholder="Exercise Name"/>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Set</th>
            <th>Reps</th>
            <th>Rest</th>
            <th>Comments</th>
         </tr>
         <tr v-for= "(row,k) in rows" :key="k">
             <td scope="row">
                 <i class="fa fa-trash" v-on:click="delRow(k,row)"></i>
             </td >
             <td>
                 <input class="form-control" type="number"v-model="row.set_num" readonly="readonly"/>
             </td>
             <td>\
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="row.num_of_reps" placeholder="10"/>\
             </td>\
             <td>\
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="row.rest_time"placeholder="1:30"/>\
             </td>\
             <td>\
                 <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="row.comments"/>\
             </td>\
        </tr>\
    </table>\
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" v-on:click="addRow">\
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>\
            Add Row\
        </button>\
</div>',
    data() {
        return {
            set_number: 2,
            rows: [{
                exercise:"exercise",
                set_num: 1,
                num_of_reps: "",
                rest_time: "",
                comments: ""
            }]
        }
    },
    methods: {
        addRow: function () {
            this.rows.push({
                exercise:"exercise",
                set_num: this.set_number++,
                num_of_reps: "",
                rest_time: "",
                comments: ""
            });
        },
        delRow: function (k, row) {
            let row_index = this.rows.indexOf(row);
            if (row_index > 0) {
                this.rows.splice(row_index, 1);
            }
            this.set_number = 1;
            for (let i in this.rows) {
                this.rows[i].set_num = this.set_number;
                this.set_number++;
            };
        }

    }
});

let temp = new Vue({
    el: ".temp",


});
```

Comment: please some tried work and snippet from your data

Comment: I abandoned the idea of using v-html and instead went with creating a template component. The template tags on the html page work properly since each table is doing as it should. However, I am not sure how to dynamically create more of them on the page, for instance, if a button were clicked.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add these tables to your HTML is by using a creating a separate table-component. 
And then add these table-components dynamically by using a `v-for` attribute in your table-component tag.
Then you could create an array containing any necessary properties for your table-component. The `v-for` could then loop over this array and create a new component for every item in the array. Let me clarify this with an example:

```js
const ListItem = {
  props: [
    'text'
  ],
  template: "<div> {{ text }} </div>",
}

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#vue-instance',

  components: {
    listitem: ListItem
  },
  data: {
    elements: []
  },
  methods: {
    addElement: function() {
      this.elements.push("This is a new instance")
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="vue-instance">
  <button @click="addElement">
     Add an element
   </button>

  <listitem v-for="(element, index) in elements" :text="element" :key="index">
  </listitem>
</div>
```